# Aborting/cleaning up an invalid database connecton from pool in Tomcat

Tags: java, sql, oracle, connection, tomcat7

I'm having problems with the connection pool in Tomcat after a database outage.

There's this heartbeat service servlet that won't come back up after a database outage.

I've already tried the [standard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030512/how-to-remove-invalid-database-connection-from-pool), and beyond, specifically:

1. Adding to the Resource section in server.xml

   ```
   validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
   testOnBorrow="true"
   removeAbandoned="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
   logAbandoned="true"
   ```
2. Trying to close the connection with a check to validity:

   ```
   if (connection != null && !connection.isValid(10)) {
       connection.close();
   }
   ```

   (Resulted in `java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed`)
3. Trying to `abort` the connection (not sure whether done right)

   ```
   if (connection != null && !connection.isValid(10)) {
       connection.abort();
   }
   ```

   (Resulted in `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.sql.Connection.abort(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)V`)

Tries 2) and 3) show that indeed the connection is invalid, and it knows it. The question is - how to destroy it?

Tomcat version: 7.0.29

Comment: If you want to close a connection, just close it: don't check for validity. An already closed connection will not (or: should not according to the JDBC spec) throw an exception if closed. Also this suggests that you are keeping a connection for longer than necessary: close connections as soon as you are done with them (especially if you use a connection pool).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - An already closed connection will not throw an exception, but an open invalid one will. Furthermore, this is not the case for connections that have been properly closed (or not), but those that have been abruptly and catastrophically ended by something beyond the apps control.

Comment: How did this go? Did you find a reliable solution?

Answer (score 1):

The pool will destroy the invalid connection for you thanks to "testOnBorrow=true" setting (note that the "Abandoned" settings only apply to connections which are not returned to the pool).
So this is how it should go:

- servlet borrows connection, does queries and returns connection to the pool.
- servlet borrows connection, database crashes, servlet receives all kinds of horrible SQL errors but **still returns connection to the pool**.
- database has restarted
- on next heartbeat, servlet borrows connection. Tomcat's pool will "test on borrow", find that the old connection is broken, removes (and closes) connection, tries another, finds that it is also broken, etc, and THEN the pool decides to create a new connection, test it OK and hands it over to the servlet.
- servlet receives new valid connection, does queries and returns connection to the pool.

I'm not sure how Tomcat's pool behaves when a "test on borrow" indicates a connection is broken (1): it might not create new connections right away or throw an error when it can't get a valid connection from the pool. But I expect the pool to effectively flush itself and re-populate with new (valid) connection.

(1) That is, if the "test on borrow" is actually done which [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/w46e3R3yG6I) indicates is not the case ...

---

If the pool does not flush itself, you can try to do this programmatically once you find connections are invalid. I have not tried this before, hopefully you can get it to work. Following method is described [here](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-close-all-connections-in-a-Tomcat-container-db-connection-pool-td1989586.html):

Reach into the JNDI context, pull-out the DataSource object, cross your fingers, cast it to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.[DataSource](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html), and call the `purge()` method.

Alterntively, use [JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JMX) and call the [purge](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/jmx/ConnectionPoolMBean.html#purge%28%29) method via the MBean.

If you experience hanging threads after a database crash, you might have to resort to a work around described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644901/3080094) answer.

Comment: Agreed with the flow here. Note, your ``abort()`` method returning ``NoSuchMethodError`` is caused because ``abort()`` was introduced in Java 7 (JDBC 4.1) and is probably not implemented by your driver. Shameless plug: as one of the authors of [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) I encourage you to give our pool a try.

Comment: @vanOekel - The process you outlined is how I also imagined it would work. There's just one problem - it doesn't... I'll do some research on why it doesn't work, but right now changing the config did not have any effect - the service stays down (to date - maximum time reached until Tomcat restart: 2 days)

Comment: @GregPK OK, so not really an answer but information about how the solution should work. I've updated the answer with a manual `purge` alternative. Shameless plug: I'll test to see if the process works with [Yapool](http://yapool.googlecode.com/).

Comment: @vanOekel That's an interesting option - will give it a go when I have the chance.

Comment: I've used the option in a JBoss environment. Testing showed it was "good enough" but not bullet proof (I added an additional comment in the answer about hanging threads).

Comment: Verified with a [unit test](https://code.google.com/p/yapool/source/browse/trunk/yapool/yapool-core/src/test/java/nl/fw/yapool/sql/TestInvalid.java) that [Yapool](http://yapool.googlecode.com/) follows the flow as described in the answer. There is no magic happening here (just basic housekeeping) so if Tomcat's JDBC pool cannot do this, it should be considered a bug/missing feature in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to dispose an ill java.sql.connection from Tomcat jdbc connection pool,

we may do this explicitly in the program.
Unwrap it into an `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection, setDiscarded(true)`
and close the JDBC connection finally, the `ConnectionPool` will remove the underlying connection once it has been returned.

```
(ConnectionPool.returnConnection(....))
                    PooledConnection pconn = conn.unwrap(PooledConnection.class);
                    pconn.setDiscarded(true);
                    conn.close();
```